# Window class style CS_NOCLOSE does not work after calling to RecreateWnd

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need a form to disable the menu Close button (and also disable closing with Alt-F4) so I used the [`CS_NOCLOSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729176(v=vs.85).aspx) class style. it works as expected if I set it in the `CreateParams`:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;  
  Params.WindowClass.style := Params.WindowClass.style or CS_NOCLOSE;
end;
```

The close button is disabled and you can't close the window with ALT+F4 (I have my own close button).

Now I added a flag: `FNoCloseButton` which initially is set to `False`.

```
procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  if FNoCloseButton then
    Params.WindowClass.style := Params.WindowClass.style or CS_NOCLOSE;
end;
```

And after the forms is created I have this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FNoCloseButton := True;
  RecreateWnd;
end;
```

After clicking Button1, The Window is re-created but the `CS_NOCLOSE` has no effect now, and ignored.

Why is that behavior? Why can't I change Window class *style* after it has been created? (I  thought I could because the `SetClassLong` api exists)

I also tried [`SetClassLong`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633588(v=vs.85).aspx) with:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetClassLong(Self.Handle, GCL_STYLE, GetClassLong(Self.Handle, GCL_STYLE) or CS_NOCLOSE);
  DrawMenuBar(Self.Handle); // Must call this to invalidate
end;
```

That works. The close is disabled (plus Alt-F4), BUT the system menu item "Close" is visible and I can close the window by clicking it. so the behavior with `SetClassLong` is a bit different.

What am I missing?

Comment: See [How do I enable and disable the minimize, maximize, and close buttons in my caption bar?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100604-00/?p=13803/) and [Modifying the CS_NOCLOSE style does affect all windows of the class, just not necessarily in an immediately noticeable way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150305-00/?p=44533).

Comment: @IInspectable, Thanks. I'll look into it.

Comment: What I can't understand is why the `RecreateWnd` which calls `DestroyWindow` (and re-create it) wont use the `CS_NOCLOSE`.

Comment: Neither do I, but maybe there's a reason why Raymond Chen put the code that modifies this class style in *italics*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
> begin
>   inherited;
>   if FNoCloseButton then
>     Params.WindowClass.style := Params.WindowClass.style or CS_NOCLOSE;
> end;
> ```

The line that modifies the window's class information in the above code has no effect because the class is already registered the first time round the code runs; when `FNoCloseButton` is false.

After you call `RecreateWindow`, the VCL destroys and creates the window but does not attempt to re-register the class which would fail with `ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS`. You could argue that not de-registering the class when destroying the window is a design error, but that's not so. Do not forget that you can have an instance or multiple instances of a form class alive at different times of a VCL application's lifetime.

For a solution, if you can make sure that the window you're destroying is the only instance of its kind, you can de-register the class yourself. Then the VCL, querying the class information and finding it to be not registered, will register it for you before creating the window. Otherwise you have to use `SetClassLong[Ptr]` as you're doing already.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure DestroyHandle; override;
    ...

..

procedure TForm1.DestroyHandle;
begin
  inherited;
  if not winapi.windows.UnregisterClass(PChar(ClassName), HInstance) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! this now works as expected. I *assumed* `DestroyWindowHandle` will unregistered the window class, so I did not even checked the source code.